# Android-How to wait for AlertDialog check?

Tags: android, error-handling, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am creating an `AlertDialog` using an `AlertDialog.Builder` and showing it. After showing it, I need to pause application until the user comfirms the Dialog.

I exactly need to pause in a method showing Dialog thread, because its calling method throws a fatal error after return.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: "After showing it, i need to pause application until user comfirms Dialog" -- there is no such concept in Android. "I exactly need to pause in a method showing Dialog thread" -- dialogs do not have threads in Android. All UI, whether it is an activity or a dialog, is rendered via the main application ("UI") thread. "because it's calling method throws fatal error after return" -- presumably, you have a bug in your application that you need to fix. Perhaps you should consider editing your question, providing the stack trace of your "fatal error" along with the relevant portions of code.

Comment: Please attach your code in the question

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can't pause the UI-Thread, as it will result in the OS showing the `Application is not responding` dialog after about 5 seconds of being paused.

Also, as mentioned by CommonsWare in the comments, Dialogs don't operate in a separate thread.

Without seeing your code it's a bit difficult to answer, but what I could suggest right now is place all the code you need to "pause" in an `AsyncTask`.

You can place all the code before the pause in the `onPreExecute()` method, than show your dialog, and in the `doInBackground()` method, maybe in a while loop or something with volatile variables or something (this code runs on a background thread so it won't stuck the UI-Thread) and then the code after the pause in the `onPostExecute()` method.
both `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` operates on the UI-Thread. the `onPost` is called after the `doInBackground` has finished.

But again, if you'd show some code of the pause it would be easier to help you.

Further reading: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this is to use threads. In a non-UI thread, call your `AlertDialog`'s `show()` method using the `runOnUiThread()` method of your `Activity`. Call `Object.wait()` in your non-UI thread, and call `Object.notifyAll()` in your `AlertDialog`'s `OnClickListener`. The non-UI thread will then wait until the user clicks on your `AlertDialog`.